# How to get customer Phone number in Abandoned Cart?

Tags: magento-1.9, grid, reports, abandoned-cart

Currently I'm getting Customer name, email and product amount, price in Abdandont cart reports.

I am getting reports on following page in Magento ver. 1.9.2.4 Admin panel.
System > Shopping Basket > Abandoned Baskets

I have tried to add manually an additional field for phone number in magento abandoned carts grid.

See here: [image]

But Its not capturing phone number, and field displays empty results. 
I have used following code:

```
<?php

/**
 * Adminhtml abandoned shopping carts report grid block
 *
 * @category   Mage
 * @package    Mage_Adminhtml
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Shopcart_Abandoned_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Grid_Shopcart
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('gridAbandoned');
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        /** @var $collection Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Quote_Collection */
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/quote_collection');

        $filter = $this->getParam($this->getVarNameFilter(), array());
        if ($filter) {
            $filter = base64_decode($filter);
            parse_str(urldecode($filter), $data);
        }

        if (!empty($data)) {
            $collection->prepareForAbandonedReport($this->_storeIds, $data);
        } else {
            $collection->prepareForAbandonedReport($this->_storeIds);
        }

// var_dump($collection);
// die();
        //Custom Join to show phone number
        //

    // Get customer telephone.
        $collection->getSelect()
        ->joinLeft(
        array('table_billing'=>'customer_entity_int'),
        ('table_billing.entity_id=main_table.customer_id AND table_billing.attribute_id=31'), // 'default_billing' attribute id = 13
        array('table_billing_value'=>'value')
        )

 ->joinLeft(
    array('table_billing_telephone'=>'customer_address_entity_varchar'),
    ('table_billing_telephone.entity_id=`table_billing`.`value` AND table_billing_telephone.attribute_id=31'), // 'telephone' attribute id = 31 
    array('telephone'=>'value')
    );   
// var_dump($collection);
// die();

        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
               //return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Grid_Shopcart::_prepareCollection();
    }

    protected function _addColumnFilterToCollection($column)
    {
        $field = ( $column->getFilterIndex() ) ? $column->getFilterIndex() : $column->getIndex();
        $skip = array('subtotal', 'customer_name', 'email'/*, 'created_at', 'updated_at'*/);

        if (in_array($field, $skip)) {
            return $this;
        }

        parent::_addColumnFilterToCollection($column);
        return $this;
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn('customer_name', array(
            'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('Customer Name'),
            'index'     =>'customer_name',
            'sortable'  =>false
        ));

        $this->addColumn('email', array(
            'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('Email'),
            'index'     =>'email',
            'sortable'  =>false
        ));
         $this->addColumn('telephone', array(
              'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('Phone'),
              'index'     =>'telephone',
              'filter_index' => 'table_billing.attribute_id',
             'sortable'  =>false
         ));


        $this->addColumn('items_count', array(
            'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('Number of Items'),
            'width'     =>'80px',
            'align'     =>'right',
            'index'     =>'items_count',
            'sortable'  =>false,
            'type'      =>'number'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('items_qty', array(
            'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('Quantity of Items'),
            'width'     =>'80px',
            'align'     =>'right',
            'index'     =>'items_qty',
            'sortable'  =>false,
            'type'      =>'number'
        ));

        if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('website')) {
            $storeIds = Mage::app()->getWebsite($this->getRequest()->getParam('website'))->getStoreIds();
        } else if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('group')) {
            $storeIds = Mage::app()->getGroup($this->getRequest()->getParam('group'))->getStoreIds();
        } else if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('store')) {
            $storeIds = array((int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('store'));
        } else {
            $storeIds = array();
        }
        $this->setStoreIds($storeIds);
        $currencyCode = $this->getCurrentCurrencyCode();

        $this->addColumn('subtotal', array(
            'header'        => Mage::helper('reports')->__('Subtotal'),
            'width'         => '80px',
            'type'          => 'currency',
            'currency_code' => $currencyCode,
            'index'         => 'subtotal',
            'sortable'      => false,
            'renderer'      => 'adminhtml/report_grid_column_renderer_currency',
            'rate'          => $this->getRate($currencyCode),
        ));

        $this->addColumn('coupon_code', array(
            'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('Applied Coupon'),
            'width'     =>'80px',
            'index'     =>'coupon_code',
            'sortable'  =>false
        ));

        $this->addColumn('created_at', array(
            'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('Created At'),
            'width'     =>'170px',
            'type'      =>'datetime',
            'index'     =>'created_at',
            'filter_index'=>'main_table.created_at',
            'sortable'  =>false
        ));

        $this->addColumn('updated_at', array(
            'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('Updated At'),
            'width'     =>'170px',
            'type'      =>'datetime',
            'index'     =>'updated_at',
            'filter_index'=>'main_table.updated_at',
            'sortable'  =>false
        ));

        $this->addColumn('remote_ip', array(
            'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('IP Address'),
            'width'     =>'80px',
            'index'     =>'remote_ip',
            'sortable'  =>false
        ));

        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportAbandonedCsv', Mage::helper('reports')->__('CSV'));
        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportAbandonedExcel', Mage::helper('reports')->__('Excel XML'));

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/customer/edit', array('id'=>$row->getCustomerId(), 'active_tab'=>'cart'));
    }
}
```

I took help from here:
[Collection loads wrong data?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8535/collection-loads-wrong-data)

I've made changes in following file:

/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Report/Shopcart/Abandoned/Grid.php

but it did not work. Can you please guide me through.

The attribute ID i have double checked from database and its 31 for phone number.

Answer (score 0):

If you have customer email then you can their data very easily.
you just need to load customer using their email like:

```
     $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");

     $customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite('admin')->getId());

   $customer_Data = $customer->loadByEmail($email);
```

now Print $customer_Data you will get whole data of customer as well as customer number.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not good developer, I need help, on following file, what code I can add? /public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Report/Shopcart/Abandoned/Grid.php  In my code which I have posted in question, anyway to tweak, if totally new code i have to add then where? Thanks

Comment: @Zubi are you able to get customer email id?

Comment: Yes @Shubham, I am getting email already, because there is a plugin to get this, but phone number is not there, which I want to add manually.  I am going to show you the whole code of the file. so may you can get idea of my issue.

Comment: please check my question again, I have updated the full code from the file.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this solution, it worked for me

http://mydons.com/how-to-show-additional-fields-in-magento-abandoned-carts-grid/